# angularjs get another property of the selected ng-repeat option to pass into another model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have a list of users, and I do an ng-repeat on the list as seen below.
I pass the id of the user to the model, however, I am trying to pass the same selected user's email to another model like:

```
<span>The selected user's email is : {{myModel.email}} </span>
```

but I get nothing. Fail! What should I do to fix it up?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <ui-select ng-model="myModel.user" name="user" theme="selectize" required ng-change="myModel.email = user.email" title="Choose user">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select user">{{$select.selected.firstName}} {{$select.selected.lastName}}
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="user.id as user in userList | userFilter:$select.search">
            <div ng-bind-html="user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName | highlight: $select.search"></div>
            <small>
                email: {{user.email}}
            </small>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
    <br/>
    <span>The selected user's email is : {{myModel.email}} </span>
</div>
```

and here is the controller:

```
$firebaseArray(MyDataBase.ref('users').orderByKey()).$loaded().then(function (res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (res[i].$id !== current.uid) {
            $scope.userList.push({
                id: res[i].$id,
                firstName: res[i].firstName,
                lastName: res[i].lastName,
                email: res[i].email
            });
        } else {
            defaultUser = res[i];
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function first and loop through the selected id to get the corresponding email:

```
$scope.userModelEmail = {};
$scope.getUserEmail = function (id) {

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.userList.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.userList[i].id === id){

            return $scope.userModelEmail.email = $scope.userList[i].email;
        }
    }

    console.log($scope.userModelEmail.email);

}
```

and of course, use the `ng-change` to pass the id to the function:

```
ng-change="getUserEmail(myModel.user)"
```

and you can reflect it here:

```
<span>The selected user's email is : {{userModelEmail.email}} </span>
```